# LibGDX: Put new value to json

Tags: libgdx

I'm using `JsonReader` and `JsonValue` like below:

```
JsonReader json = new JsonReader();
JsonValue jsonValue = json.parse(Gdx.files.internal("file.json"));
```

My question is How to add a new item to `jsonValue` or update values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
jsonValue.remove("name");
jsonValue.addChild("name", new JsonValue("new Value"));
```